# How to build CDC SSIS Package to load multiple tables between source and destination?

Tags: sql, azure, ssis

I had a CDC package built for a single table that works perfectly, but now I want to improve scalability more here, I want to have a package that can data from multiple source tables to destionation tables, is there any way I can do this?

What are my best options here?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a parent package that triggers multiple child packages for each table. A little time consuming process but this way you will have more control on processing of each table, and in future if you want to add/remove tables you can do it without affecting existing single package.

I would recommend you to go through this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/change-data-capture/perform-an-incremental-load-of-multiple-tables?view=sql-server-ver15), as it mentions 2 ways to do the same:

1. Use a parent package and child packages.
2. Use multiple Data Flow tasks in a single package

Comment: still I need to create multiple child packages? there is now way i can build this dynamically?